# Get nested delegate type ref. from inside a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I tried to retrieve the TYPE for "PreProcess" from DomainDB class using

```
Type.GetType("DomainDBManager.DomainDB`1[System.String]+PreProcess")
```

but this is returning null. Is there anyway to get the Public Field "PreProcess" using Type.GetType?

namespace DomainDBManager
{
public class DomainDB<T>
{
        public Action<string> PreProcess;
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently trying to get a *type* by name - `PreProcess` is a *field* of the `DomainDB<T>` type, so `Type.GetType` isn't going to work. You need to get the type first, and then get the field from that:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("DomainDBManager.DomainDB`1[System.String]");
FieldInfo field = type.GetField("PreProcess");
Type fieldType = field.FieldType;
```

Comment: Yes thats right. My requirement is to get the Type for a public delegate inside the generic class.

Comment: @AJP: When you say a "public delegate" that's not very clear... if it were a delegate type declaration, your original code would be fine. However, it's a *field* whose type happens to be a delegate type. The fact that it's a delegate type is actually irrelevant.

Comment: I actually meant Field, sorry for the confusion. The solution which you provided worked perfectly fine. Thanks